# Ordering certificates from the Corella Registry Office in Spain

Tags: vital-records, spain

This is the [website](https://sede.mjusticia.gob.es/eCertificados/CertificadoDefuncion.do?lang=en_gb&idtramite=1215327470343&idpagina=1215197884559) that I use to order Spanish certificates. I am slightly confused though because I can never find Corella as a Registry Office in the lists.

First the **Region**:

[image: Region]

Next, the **Province**:

[image: Province]

Then, when filling in the details for the certificate you choose the **Registry Office**:

[image: Office]

As you can see, Corella is not listed! But I have checked the official maps and Corella falls within the overall Tudela area:

[image: Map]

So I can't work out how to select **Corella** as an office location. The original links for ordering are advertised [here](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Order_Spain_Vital_Records_Online).

Comment: Not every city has a Registry Office. On the contrary, just big ones do. You can check the list of Registry Offices in Navarra in their website --> https://www.navarra.es/home_es/Temas/Justicia/registro+civil+navarra.htm

Comment: @fedorqui But I have been sent some certicates (after Tudela office forwarded them to Corella). The address on those envelopes is "Plaza de España, s/n, 31591, Corella, Navarra".

Comment: @fedorqui So would I continue to go through Tudela and have the request internally redirected?

Comment: The address you mention seems to correspond to the City Council. I am not very aware of how this works, but sometimes bureaucracy allows some things in the city itself, while others need biggest entities to do so. I think going through Tudela can be a good move, since they can redirect if necessary. Otherwise, you can phone the Corella city council and see if they can explain where exactly you can ask for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://www.mjusticia.gob.es/BUSCADIR/ServletControlador the correct office is Tudela.

[image: Office]

So they would forward if needed to Corella City Hall:

[image: Envelope with City Hall Address]